# Kafka 2.1.0 Java Consumer vs Scala Consumer

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I would like to upgrade my team's Kafka clusters from version 0.10.1.1 to version 2.1.0. By the way, Kafka official document says the following words.

[Kafka Official Docu](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_2_1_0)

> Note that the older Scala clients, which are no longer maintained, do not support the message format introduced in 0.11, so to avoid conversion costs (or to take advantage of exactly once semantics), the newer Java clients must be used.

I do not understand that sentence well. Currently our team is using the Kafka Consumer Application written in Scala. But should we turn this into Java? If we use the application written in Scala at present, I do not know exactly what disadvantages it can have.

Comment: The Scala Kafka clients are no longer supported, you should use the *Java* implementation from your Scala code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "no longer supported" means "I can use it but it will cause performance problems and other problems."? Right?

Comment: Using it means if you update your Kafka Brokers from 0.10.1.1 to 2.1.0, your clients will no longer "speak" the same protocol, and will probably not work.

Comment: Okay. If I want use the v2.1.0 Kafka Cluster and Consumer clients completely, I should transform my Scala code to Java.... Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it OK to write an application using Kafka Sink Connect as it is?

Comment: @Dogil, You don't need to change your Scala code to Java. Given Scala runs on the JVM too, it is completely interoperable with Java. You only need to change the parts of your code that directly speak with Kafka to use the Java API instead _(still in scala code)_.

Comment: Thank you Luis~! I executed some tests for this issue and I got a result that Scala or Java code with version 0.10.1.1 were working well... And codes with version 2.1.0 also !

Comment: And.. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez,, I have a question. Is there only two changes to the 2.1.0 version of the consumer code in the 0.10.1.1 version of the code? poll(long) -> poll(Duration), and some exceptions...

Comment: @Dogil I have no idea, sorry. I have not used Kafka - I just point out that you could call Java from Scala.

Comment: Your previous comments have been a lot of help. Thank you~!

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing the old Scala-based `kafka.consumer` and `kafka.producer` packages that were in the Kafka core module with the new `kafka-clients` dependency, that is implemented in Java.

If your imports are these, you will be fine, and don't need to use different classes, and might only need to re-write a few parameters of methods calls after an upgrade

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
```

> should we turn this into Java? If we use the application written in Scala at present, I do not know exactly what disadvantages it can have

Java is more verbose, and doesn't have as nice a type-system as Scala. You're welcome to write the same code in Scala, Kotlin, Clojure, etc... At the end of the day, it's all running in the JVM

Comment: Thank @cricket_007.. The sentence 'The Scala consumers, which have been deprecated since 0.11.0.0, have been removed. The Java consumer has been the recommended option since 0.10.0.0. Note that the Scala consumers in 1.1.0 (and older) will continue to work even if the brokers are upgraded to 2.0.0.' in Kafka official documents seams to mean that I should not use Scala.

Comment: @Dogil No. It is saying not to use the **client APIs based on** Scala. You can use the new Java-based API in any JVM language

Comment: For example, the Scala Kafka Streams API was added in Kafka 2.0, and actually is recommended for those using Scala, because it is easier to use than the Java API.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I get the picture now.